# Trying to display PDF stream to web page for printing

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, stream

I am trying to take a memory stream that contains either HTML or PDF (my choice).

The issue that I am running into is that I cannot render this content to my page. The content will show on the page, but it all garbled on the screen.  If I take that same stream and save it to a file and open it up it displays correctly.

Am I incorrectly setting something wrong when it returns from the server?

On my web page I have:

```
function getData()
{
        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: '/Main/MyController/GetPrintData',
            data: {
                reportID: 1,
                format: 'pct',
                cumeReach: 'abc',
                showAddl: 'true',
                precision: 'false'
            },
            contentType: 'application/pdf' //'text/html'
        }).success(function (result) {
            $('#reportData').append(result);
        }).error(function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
                alert(xhr.status);
                alert(thrownError);
        });
};
```

The HTML looks like this:

```
<html>
  <head>
     <title>Print3</title>
  </head>
  <body onload="getData();">
    <div id="reportData">

    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Syntax error at `<div id="reportData" />` , `div` is not  a self-closing tag

Comment: Updated the HTML to reflect what is on my page.

Comment: I was also trying to go this route..
    }).done(function (result) {
                $('#reportData').append(@Html.Raw(result));

However I get a syntax error that result is not defined.  Why can't I wrap that with the @Html.Raw?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that my original solution was correct.
After examining the code I discovered an issue with the way the memory stream are created.

I am using Aspose to create the stream.
I previously had
    return book.SaveToStream();
I replaced it with
    Stream finalStream = new MemoryStream();
    book.Save(finalStream, saveOptions);
    return finalStream;

Once I made that change the display worked!

Answer (score 0):

Note `.success()` , `.error()` are deprecated in jQuery ; could substitute `.done()` , `.fail()` for `.success()` , `.error()`

Try

html

```
<embed width="100%" height="100%" name="plugin" id="result" />
```

js

```
$("#result")[0].src = URL.createObjectURL(new Blob([result], {"type":"application/pdf"}));
```

Comment: I did try this solution however nothing is rendering on my view.